# Adapting Superfish, some hints and tips needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, superfish

I have a question re: adapting superfish.

I'm developing a site using wordpress and thematic. It users Superfish for its menus straight out of the box. This is all fine.

I want to have a slightly different way of displaying 3rd Tier sub menus... ive attached a link to an image for ease of use:

[menu](http://dan-price.co.uk/elliea/wp-content/themes/ellieatkins/Homepageno-bkgrnd.png)

I understand that the effect is determined by the supersubs.js...

Here is the code Im using:
superfish.js

```
(function(b){b.fn.superfish=function(k){var g=b.fn.superfish,j=g.c,f=b(['<span class="',j.arrowClass,'"> &#187;</span>'].join("")),i=function(){var c=b(this),l=d(c);clearTimeout(l.sfTimer);c.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl()},e=function(){var c=b(this),m=d(c),l=g.op;clearTimeout(m.sfTimer);m.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){l.retainPath=(b.inArray(c[0],l.$path)>-1);c.hideSuperfishUl();if(l.$path.length&&c.parents(["li.",l.hoverClass].join("")).length<1){i.call(l.$path)}},l.delay)},d=function(c){var l=c.parents(["ul.",j.menuClass,":first"].join(""))[0];g.op=g.o[l.serial];return l},h=function(c){c.addClass(j.anchorClass).append(f.clone())};return this.each(function(){var c=this.serial=g.o.length;var m=b.extend({},g.defaults,k);m.$path=b("li."+m.pathClass,this).slice(0,m.pathLevels).each(function(){b(this).addClass([m.hoverClass,j.bcClass].join(" ")).filter("li:has(ul)").removeClass(m.pathClass)});g.o[c]=g.op=m;b("li:has(ul)",this)[(b.fn.hoverIntent&&!m.disableHI)?"hoverIntent":"hover"](i,e).each(function(){if(m.autoArrows){h(b(">a:first-child",this))}}).not("."+j.bcClass).hideSuperfishUl();var l=b("a",this);l.each(function(n){var o=l.eq(n).parents("li");l.eq(n).focus(function(){i.call(o)}).blur(function(){e.call(o)})});m.onInit.call(this)}).each(function(){var c=[j.menuClass];if(g.op.dropShadows&&!(b.browser.msie&&b.browser.version<7)){c.push(j.shadowClass)}b(this).addClass(c.join(" "))})};var a=b.fn.superfish;a.o=[];a.op={};a.IE7fix=function(){var c=a.op;if(b.browser.msie&&b.browser.version>6&&c.dropShadows&&c.animation.opacity!=undefined){this.toggleClass(a.c.shadowClass+"-off")}};a.c={bcClass:"sf-breadcrumb",menuClass:"sf-js-enabled",anchorClass:"sf-with-ul",arrowClass:"sf-sub-indicator",shadowClass:"sf-shadow"};a.defaults={hoverClass:"sfHover",pathClass:"overideThisToUse",pathLevels:1,delay:800,animation:{opacity:"show"},speed:"normal",autoArrows:true,dropShadows:true,disableHI:false,onInit:function(){},onBeforeShow:function(){},onShow:function(){},onHide:function(){}};b.fn.extend({hideSuperfishUl:function(){var e=a.op,d=(e.retainPath===true)?e.$path:"";e.retainPath=false;var c=b(["li.",e.hoverClass].join(""),this).add(this).not(d).removeClass(e.hoverClass).find(">ul").hide().css("visibility","hidden");e.onHide.call(c);return this},showSuperfishUl:function(){var e=a.op,d=a.c.shadowClass+"-off",c=this.addClass(e.hoverClass).find(">ul:hidden").css("visibility","visible");a.IE7fix.call(c);e.onBeforeShow.call(c);c.animate(e.animation,e.speed,function(){a.IE7fix.call(c);e.onShow.call(c)});return this}})})(jQuery);
```

supersubs.js

```
(function(a){a.fn.supersubs=function(b){var     c=a.extend({},a.fn.supersubs.defaults,b);return this.each(function(){var d=a(this);var e=a.meta?a.extend({},c,d.data()):c;var f=a('<li id="menu-fontsize">&#8212;</li>').css({padding:0,position:"absolute",top:"-999em",width:"auto"}).appendTo(d).width();a("#menu-fontsize").remove();$ULs=d.find("ul");$ULs.each(function(l){var k=$ULs.eq(l);var j=k.children();var g=j.children("a");var m=j.css("white-space","nowrap").css("float");var h=k.add(j).add(g).css({"float":"none",width:"auto"}).end().end()[0].clientWidth/f;h+=e.extraWidth;if(h>e.maxWidth){h=e.maxWidth}else{if(h<e.minWidth){h=e.minWidth}}h+="em";k.css("width",h);j.css({"float":m,width:"100%","white-space":"normal"}).each(function(){var n=a(">ul",this);var i=n.css("left")!==undefined?"left":"right";n.css(i,h)})})})};a.fn.supersubs.defaults={minWidth:9,maxWidth:25,extraWidth:0}})(jQuery);
```

I was just wondering if anyone had had any success editing it to achieve the effect I need here? Im talking about the positioning specifically. By default the third level appears to the right of the second.

Is their an alternative method anyone could recommend?

For completeness here is the link to the site:
[test site](http://dan-price.co.uk/elliea/)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest 3rd level as sub ul of second level, rather place the links in second level LI and give them a different class to use css to modify alignment and color

Comment: worst case you can move them to second level with jQuery, but cleaner to do it on server

Comment: Could you expand a little bit, assume Im a complete idiot! Thanks

Comment: point was about being able to restructure existing html within php in wordpress.. shouldn't be hard but if it is can also maniulate the html with jQuery

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Makes sense but I'm convinced there must be a way to do it by editing supersubs.js as its controlling the CSS, or at least a way to do it with a new jquery script

Comment: script is designed to handle unlimited nesting, yes..could be rewritten but far more work. I've helped with a lot of support for superfish for years in jQuery forum